# How does one know who voted on a question of theirs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, voting

It's happened a few times when I down-voted on someone's question, and somehow the OP is able to figure out that it was me who voted. I have tried to find such a thing but do not see this possible. Is it possible? Where to see it if so? Does one need a certain reputation to be able to see? Or is it just a guess?

Comment: Did you comment after you downvoted?

Comment: Voting is anonymous

Comment: No one can see that you downvoted them unless you leave a comment telling them.

Comment: The OP doesn't know it was you. He just made a guess. (I don't see why it's necessary to downvote this, though?)

Comment: They can guess. Sometimes they guess right.

Comment: They may have remembered how much reputation you had and deduced it was you. Best bet is to ignore and make them wonder to torture their mind for the rest of their life.

Comment: @0A0D That would only work if you downvoted an answer...

Comment: I don't necessarily have a problem with it, it's just strange how people know that. I voted on someone's question from long back, unrelated to a current conversation, and somehow that person knew it was me and confronted me.

Comment: @Jerry that seems weird. Can you post a link?

Comment: I'll have to find it...

Comment: @JerryDodge Perhaps the conversation was getting a bit heated, and they just assumed it was you that downvoted them?

Comment: It's actually not too hard to test if someone has downvoted your own answer. You can check the user's reputation from yesterday against the reputation changes today. If there is a discrepancy of say 1, (and most users don't cast multiple downvotes in a day) you can infer that the user cast a downvote. Then by deleting/undeleting your answer, and watching the recalcs affect the user's rep, you can confirm that the user downvoted your answer. I've helped a few people before who were *really* curious about who downvoted their answer (if they already suspected a particular person).

Comment: Could be, and actually I remember my question with this had its comments cleared. It was a while ago.

Comment: @Yannis: Ah yes, most people don't complain directly about downvoting a question so that's why I got confused

Comment: @Mysticial OP: "It's happened a few times when I down-voted on someone's **question**"...

Comment: @Yannis I know. But I thought I'd add that it's possible to track answer downvotes if you suspect you know who it is.

Comment: That said, I want to make it clear that I don't go around "helping" everyone track who downvoted their answer. Since votes are indeed supposed to be annoymous. So I only do so if I actually know the person really well (a friend) and I trust that the person won't lash out against the downvoter.

Comment: @Mysticial Hehe, "annoymous". You just coined a very concise neologism for how downvotees sometimes feel.

Comment: @GertArnold Dammit... That's what happens when my hands get ahead of my head and I don't proofread. :)

Comment: I would have settled for the answer "One does not simply know who voted" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. It is not even shown in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Perhaps you had commented on the post in some way.